# Javascript events not working on the Partial view loaded using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am loading a partial view (CartHeader) using AJAX and the Javascript events won't fire in the  partial view.
I tried to register the events inside the success method of the `post` but they don't seem to be working.

**_layout.cshtml :**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

<div id="divCartHeader">

</div>
</nav>
```

**CartHeader.cstml :**

```
<div class="CartHeader">


    <div class="CartButtons">
        <button type="button" id="emptyCart">Empty Cart</button>&nbsp;       
    </div>

</div>
```

**Cart.js :**

```
 var Mod = Mod || {};
    Mod.Carts = function (e) {

     if (ddlselectedVal == "ViewCart") {

      var frmViewCartValiator = $("#frmViewCart").validate({
     var url = EnvironmentURL + "Reports/Stats/GetListingsInCart" ;

     $.post(url,
            function (data) {
                 var $emailForm = $("#frmPostToEmailReports");
                 $emailForm.find("#IsCart").val(true);                                         

                 var url = $("#applicationName").val() + "/Stats/GetCartHeader";
                 if (IsCart) {
                    // Show the partial view(CartHeader)
                    $.post(url,
                          function (data) { 
                            $("#divCartHeader").html(data);
                            $('#emptyCart').on('click', function (e) {
                            alert('You Cart Header events are firing');
                                 });
                              });
                            };  
                       });
                   });    
               }
            }
```

Comment: Are you getting anything in your `console`?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your code relies on IsCart returning as true for your second $.post to fire and IsCart isn't defined anywhere in your code.  JUST for sake of testing functionality, you can add

```
var url = $("#applicationName").val() + "/Stats/GetCartHeader";
var IsCart = true;
if (IsCart) {
    ....
}
```

and this should give you the ability to test through the second $.post.  However, you will need to come back and define your own functionality and logic for how IsCart is set.